# Is this a good subjective question?

Tags: discussion, subjective

Once I opened a question on meta citing this article blog: 
[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and someone replied me: it's an old article now SE has got better, stricter and so on :-)

It's a very good article instead. Who answered me maybe was simply wrong or choose a stupid answer, but actually is very funny how many mirrors we can climb to avoid thinking again if we are right or not.

I think I understand very well the reason which pushed that guy (he was trying to help this community), but for me was also a bit sad to see a member of this community refuse the columns on which this community has been built.

**I wanted to ask on another point, but maybe my question has got too long.**

My question was:

> When I am coding and I have to choose the name of variable there are some complex cases in which I can use a name which explains what the variable is storing or what for I will use that variable.
>
> For example, in my case I have a string which contains an url which specifies only the language to be used in the website. And I will use it to make a redirection. The actual name is something like "redirectUrl" but it's not clear what I'm redirecting to.
>
> Which solutions are advised by Software Engineering in this cases?

The question is subjective, but we are not speaking of something like Yahoo Answers (and who state this should be burned out :-p). **But is this kind of question a good subjective question?**

**I would like an answer which keeps into account what is written in the article I cited.**

Comment: What does YA stand for?

Comment: one may argue that conceptually, a question this has been addressed in [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260) If your peers keep complaining about your way of doing things, be it one way or another, you better change to make them feel better

Comment: @YannisRizos: Yahoo Answers

Comment: @gnat: it's good because you linked a question which is totally opinion based but it's also well accepted here (which I think it's great since it's constructive). But I wouldn't say it addresses my question since my question is very specific while this is hugely broad. I think it's really a great example of good opinionability.

Comment: FWIW it appears to be a widely used practice to close specific questions as duplicates when these are covered by a broader canonical question, see eg [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773) at MSE

Comment: @gnat: it would be a very good discussion. A very important point. My idea is that would be an error to close a discussion speaking of how to choose the correct name in a very specific context as a duplicate of "How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?" - and I think there are some thousand of questions which would be closed if this rule would be always applied. But I think someone who is inside the community has more experience and can take a deep think on it.

Comment: @gnat: I would also say that it's important to guide the younger / less experienced / less reflexive members of SE through very well written articles like the one, written from Robert Cartaino, that I posted in my question.